# Развернуть/свернуть компонент webbrowser на форме

Tags: delphi, iwebbrowser2

Здравствуйте. У меня на форме есть 2 браузера, как сделать так, чтобы по первому клику на кнопку один из этих браузеров исчезал (сворачивался) с формы, а по второму клику появлялся (разворачивался)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ложите свой браузер на панель.
в онКлик батона пишите:

```
panel1.Visible:=not panel1.Visible;
```

Comment: ОО Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Я уже исправил, действительно свойство Visible у браузера както странно работает (точнее вообще не работает)